# Display image based on different values from dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html

I am a little stuck on how I can display images from my image folder based on different values from my  options. I want to display images of different drinks based on the users selected options. So if I select Vodka, Sweet, Blended it would display an image of a drink that fits that parameter. I have images saved as the names of the combined values of each  group.

ex: "B1X.jpg" would display an image of a boozy frappe.

**JS**

```
function displayDrink(src) {
     var mixedDrink = $("alcohol").val() + $("flavor").val() + $("type").val() + ".jpg";
     
     
     
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
     <form>
               <select id="alcohol">
                    <option value="A">Select Alcohol</option>
                    <option value="B">Vodka</option>
                    <option value="C">Whiskey</option>
                    <option value="D">Rum</option>
                    <option value="E">Tequila</option>
                    <option value="F">Gin</option>
                    <option value="G">Bourbon</option>
                    <option value="H">Scotch</option>
                    <option value="I">Vermouth</option>
                    <option value="J">Spirits</option>
                    <option value="K">Cognac</option>
                </select>
                <select id="flavor">
                    <option value="0">Select Flavor</option>
                    <option value="1">Sweet</option>
                    <option value="2">Sour</option>
                    <option value="3">Savory</option>
                    <option value="4">Spicy</option>
                    <option value="5">Smoky</option>
                    <option value="6">Bitter</option>
                    <option value="7">Fruity</option>
                    <option value="8">Herbaceous</option>
                </select>
                <select id="type">
                    <option value="W">Select Type</option>
                    <option value="X">Blended</option>
                    <option value="Y">Iced</option>
                    <option value="Z">Chilled</option>
                </select><br /><br />
     </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is `mixedDrink` the value you expect?  Do you just need to set it as the `src` of an `<img>` element?

Comment: @David Yes and have the src be determined by the users selected options.

Answer (score 1):

Have an image tag such as:

`<img class="image-container"></img>`

select the container:

`const container = document.querySelector('.image-container');`

subscribe to changes of each of your select elements:

```
const alcoholSelect = document.querySelector('#alchohol');
const flavorSelect = document.querySelector('#flavor');
const typeSelect = document.querySelector('#type');
alcoholSelect.addEventListener('change', () => handleDrinkSelect());
flavorSelect.addEventListener('change', () => handleDrinkSelect());
typeSelect.addEventListener('change', () => handleDrinkSelect());
```

add the handler: (make sure to adjust the output string to match the relative location of your images folder)

```
function handleDrinkSelect () {
  container.src = `${alcoholSelect.value}${flavorSelect.value}${typeSelect.value}.jpg`;
}
```

You could also do it more cleanly with [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)